# Google Analytics linker error. library not found for -lGGLAnalytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, linker, cocoapods

I have just added `Google Analytics` to my pods like this:

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'
```

just like GA documentation suggests. Now my project won't link. It says:

```
 library not found for -lGGLAnalytics
```

Did anyone ever encounter this? Thanks

Comment: f the project uses CocoaPods be aware to always open the .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: I open it through the workspace of course

Comment: In SearchPath header under Build Settings , Always search path set YES.  Set Framworks $(inherited),

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Solved by reseting `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` to default value.

Select your target and navigate to *Build Settings*. Under *Search Paths* select *Library Search Paths* and reset it to default by pressing backspace.

In result, the value for *Library Search Paths* should change from blank:

[image]

to default:

[image]

Diff in `.pbxproj` just removes the empty value:

[image]

---

I'm using pods version`0.39.0`, Xcode 7.2.

Comment: Please explain widely what needs to be add in Library Search path

Comment: @RMDeveloper nothing should be added. All you need (according to my comment) is to remove exiting value by selecting the field and pressing Backspace. This way you'll revert this field to the default value.

Comment: if you need to add something in this field, just make sure that you add `$(inherited)` on the first item

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was remove all but $(inherited) in Target -> Build Settings -> Other linker flags

Then of course clean and build!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and had a very strange cause and different solution from the above.

I had a working project in my normal directory and I save it to an SVN code repo. I needed to step back to a previous version for something, so I checked out a new copy from SVN and updated it back to the revision I needed.

Then I started getting the `library not found for -lGGLAnalytics` error.

It turns out that SVN doesn't really like it when you check-in `*.a` files and it ignores them by default. So my SVN repo had all of the Google Pod code but was missing the `libGGLAnalytics.a` files and a couple of other `.a` files.

How I solved it:

I copied the `Pods/Google` and `Pods/GoogleAnalytics` directories over from my real project. Then I did a `pod install` from the command line which updated my project files to reference those files that were previously missing.

I did a Build Clean and all fixed.